# Highcharts Remove null data

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I need to remove the data reading 0 in the chart here: http://jsfiddle.net/zf3m6/2/
So that each label on the x axis only shows the relevant data.
JS is:

```
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: '20 and over',
        color: 'Red',
        data: [192]

    }, {
        name: 'Under 20',
        color: 'Green',
        data: [0, 173]

    }, {
        name: 'Zero',
        color: 'Blue',
        data: [0, 0, 25.1]

    }, {
        name: 'Not Assessed',
        color: 'Black',
        data: [0, 0, 0, 1.5]

    }]
```

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/zf3m6/4/ ?

Comment: Hi, thanks that is definitely a step in the right direction.
However, I need to be able to remove the null data completely so that for example: 20 and over only shows the data for 20 and over.

Comment: In my data you have no empty points, only these which have value > 0. Anyway you can develop by base and adapt to your expectation.